# Testing React Component with enzyme mocha chai and sinon

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, mocha.js, enzyme

I have a few external libraries that I am using with my project. My React component are the wrappers written for the component which are in my external library. I am trying to write tests for these components. How can my tests make use of the JavaScript files from the external library. What configuration I should do to get this working. I have using React 16 with typescript.

mocha.opts

```
--require ts-node/register
--require jsdom-global/register
--watch-extensions tsx,ts
src/**/*.spec.tsx
src/**/*.spec.ts
```

package.json test entry

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "cross-env TS_NODE_PROJECT=\"tsconfig.testing.json\"  mocha --opts mocha.opts ",
}
```

tsconfig.testing.json

```
{
     "compilerOptions": {
     "paths": { "*": ["types/*"] },
     "baseUrl": "./src",
     "noImplicitAny": false,
     "strictNullChecks": true,
     "module": "esnext",
     "moduleResolution": "node",
     "target": "es5",
     "jsx": "react",
     "lib": [
       "dom",
       "es5",
       "es6",
       "es2016.array.include"
     ],
     "outDir": "lib"
     },
     "include": [
       "./src/**/*.ts",
       "./src/**/*.tsx"
     ]
}
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: I have written a test to check if the component was mounted. When the test executes the references from the external library is given as undefined.

Comment: Then give a [mcve] of that

Comment: is there something else I can share so you can help me find a solution, the libraries can not be shared.

Comment: The libraries are imported into my node_modules folder.